# How to specifty the main.java.srcDirs in Android studio to avoid default activity not found?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am continually getting the error default activity not found in android studio. I have updated the

```
sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/<YOUR DIRECTORY>'
} to -


sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/home/adarsh/Desktop/Desktop/android-studio/jre'
      }
```

As mentioned here.[How to add a linked source folder in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18947314/how-to-add-a-linked-source-folder-in-android-studio/22028681#22028681)

But I am getting the same error again ,please tell me what else needed to done to avoid the error default activity not found in Android studio.

Comment: `'src/main/<YOUR DIRECTORY>'`?? did your change the `<YOUR DIRECTORY>` with your directory??

Comment: Why not just put your source in the default location, `<project>/app/src/main/java` ?  And please tell me you don't keep your Java source files in the `jre` directory.

Comment: of course@Rod_Algonquin , I changed that to "src/main/home/adarsh/Desktop/Desktop/android-studio/jre" , any other suggestion.

Comment: @nasch , may you tell how to "put your source in the default location, <project>/app/src/main/java ". I installed the Android studio and am trying to run my first hello world app . I tried "which java " whose output is /usr/bin/java.

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin , I set the main.java.srcDirs as- main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/home/adarsh/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication/app/src/main/java/MyApplication.java'  . Is this correct ? I am not able to resolve the error yet.

Comment: @A.kumar `main.java.srcDirs` means the file directory of the source code, not the JRE file

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin I placed main.java.srcDirs += '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle', Is this wrong ? I aslo tried by placing main.java.srcDirs += '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java' , but still getting the same error. Please help me to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

`which java` tells you where your installation of the java platform is.  You should put your source files, such as HelloWorld.java or MainActivity.java, in the location I indicated.  The easiest way to do this is to go to Android Studio's project view and select the Android tab.  Then open the `app` node, right click `java`, and add a new class.  It will automatically be put in the right place.  Remove everything about `sourceSet` from your build file.

Comment: I did the same as you told added a class and removed everything from sourceSet ,but still getting the  same error . Is some thing needed to be add in the newly created class ? I am very beginner , any help is highly appreciated .

Comment: Have you specified your startup activity in the manifest? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9704898/how-to-set-my-activity-as-main-activity-in-android

Comment: Thanks @nasch , btw I solved it and posted as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by uninstalling and then reinstalling Android studio(to set all the paths again ).

The problem I found was "JAVA_HOME" was not set as an environment variable (I downloaded the latest jdk from oracle and indicated it's path as JAVA_HOME ).

Once I added the JAVA_HOME as my environment variable by editing the ./bashrc  the new installed Android studio automatically sets the jdk path same as "JAVA_HOME".

Thanks