Cannot open early access app for closed testers, only uninstall
I am attempting to put my app into early access closed testing via google console. I built it as apk and created a signed bundle via android studio. It uploads as aab fine and goes through review. When I reach the stage of distribution, it gives users the chance to install the app. All users as signed up as testers in the closed area. But there is then no option to open it, only uninstall it. The app also doesn't appear anywhere else on their phone - no icon is created. Am I missing something?
I have searched the advice areas and forums with no luck. I have tried multiple devices - phones and Chromebook. I'd be grateful if someone can tell me if either there is a fault with the app build and how to resolve it or if it is downloaded to a users device in an unusual area, meaning it needs a special permission to access it or similar.

Are you sure your AndroidManifest.xml entry for the start/main activity is correct? https://stackoverflow.com/q/9704898/150978

@robert hi, thank you for responding, I think that's all ok. The base .apk works fine, it's when it's getting bundled as an aab that I think the problem is occurring.

If the app is installed you can try to extract the APK files (via app or adb) and decompile them using Jadx-Gui and check how the Android manifest.xml in the final APK looks. Also check logcat after installation for install or app related errors.
